# If statement returning NO, should return YES

Tags: php, date, comparison

I'm new to PHP and trying to compare two dates within a IF statement. My issue is that the IF statement is returning NO when it should be returning YES.

```
$current_date = date('m-d-Y');
$today = strtotime($current_date);
$first_day_only = new DateTime('first day of this month');

//If today is greater than the first day of the month, then YES else NO
if($today > $first_day_only){
    echo "YES";
} else {
    echo "NO";
}
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($today, $first_day_only);` and you should understand why

Comment: I'm too much of a newb to understand why exactly, but maybe something about comparing a string with a int??

Either way, it was just enough to lead me to a solution:

Comment: If you want a good reflex, use some php function to display the value of your var, it helps to understand what really happen :) `var_dump($var);` do the job, but you can use `echo $var` if $var is a string, `print_r($var)` is usefull too...so if something doesn't works, try to understand what you really ask to your code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
 $today = new DateTime();
    $first_day_only = new DateTime('first day of this month');

    //If today is greater than the first day of the month, then YES else NO
    if($today->format('Y-m-d') > $first_day_only->format('Y-m-d')){
        echo "YES";
    } else {
        echo "NO";
    }
```